# Unicode error reading Python log file (logging)

Tags: python, logging, unicode

I am creating a log file using Pythons logging library. When I am trying to read it with python and print it on a html page (using Flask), I get:

```
<textarea cols="80" rows="20">{% for line in log %}{{line}}{% endfor %}
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 36: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I guess that this has to do with that the log file is decoded in some other decoding, but which?

This is the line setting the log file if it helps:

```
fileLogger = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename = 'log.log', when = 'midnight', backupCount = 30)
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `logging` package file handlers will encode any Unicode object you send to it to UTF-8, unless you specified a different encoding.

Use [`io.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) to read the file as UTF-8 data again, you'll get `unicode` objects again, ideal for Jinja2:

```
import io

log = io.open('log.log', encoding='utf8')
```

You could also specify a different encoding for the `TimedRotatingFileHandler` but UTF-8 is an excellent default. Use the `encoding` keyword argument if you wanted to pick a different encoding:

```
fileLogger = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(
    filename='log.log', when='midnight', backupCount=30,
    encoding='Latin1')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with flask, but if you can grab the contents of the log as a string. You can encode it to utf-8 like so:

`string = string.encode('utf-8') # string is the log's contents, now in utf-8`